# Spring Boot Application(tomcat server) was killed suddenly?

Tags: spring-boot

[image]

[image]

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAcL6.png">error log</img>
```

I want to know the reason of my application killed ,and how to prevent it occur again~!   please Daniel Newham come to help me

Comment: That is a good question. I have another one for you: How do you think we should help you debug code you don't want to show us? Please include code and post the error instead of using an image.

Comment: Please provide error message, or I think only the psychic could help you.

Comment: I have add error image [enter image desciption here]